# Render text string to image to calculate length with Wand/ImagaMagick Python

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I need to calculate the length when rendered of a lot of strings using a custom font.  From a shell script and ImageMagick I am able to do something using the annotate command line option.

```
convert -debug annotate xc: -font "customfont.ttf" -pointsize "25" -annotate 0 "this is the text" out.png
```

And then reading the width of the rendered image.

Im struggling to understand how to do this with the python 'Wand' lib.  I have created a font object, but I seem to need to define the width of the canvas to paint the font onto.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) you would use `wand.drawing.Drawing.get_font_metrics` which will return an instance of `FontMetrics` class.

Example

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing

with Image(filename='wizard:') as img:
    with Drawing() as context:
        context.font_family = 'monospace'
        context.font_size = 25
        metrics = context.get_font_metrics(img,
                                           "How BIG am I?",
                                           multiline=False)
        print(metrics)

#=> FontMetrics(character_width=25.0,
#               character_height=25.0,
#               ascender=23.0,
#               descender=-5.0,
#               text_width=170.0,
#               text_height=29.0,
#               maximum_horizontal_advance=50.0,
#               x1=0.0,
#               y1=0.0,
#               x2=19.21875,
#               y2=18.0,
#               x=170.0,
#               y=0.0)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this later.

Comment: Excellent this is exactly what I was after.  I didn't realise the trick with filename='wizard:'!

Comment: How would I go about calling text_height in the code for something like resizing the height of an image by adding the height of the text? @emcconville

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `label:` and let ImageMagick calculate the width needed for you?

```
convert -font "Arial" -pointsize 64 label:"this is the text" out.png
identify out.png
out.png PNG 396x73 396x73+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.57KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

or, more simply:

```
convert -font "Arial" -pointsize 64 label:"this is the text" -format %w info:
396
```

or, as Eric suggested:

```
convert -font "Arial" -pointsize 64 label:"this is the text" -format %w +identify result.png
396
```

Or, if you want to use `annotate`, you can make a larger canvas and trim it, like this:

```
convert -gravity west xc:white[1000x1000] -font "arial" -pointsize 32 -annotate 0 "this is the text" -trim -format %w info:
197
```

Comment: Always a good answer Mark. You can add `-format %w +identify` to the first example if you want to eliminate the `identify` step, AND keep output image

Comment: I could yes that maybe a better way.  I would prefer a python solution using the bindings because this needs to be dynamically calculated based on user input at a later stage. Thanks for the suggestion I shall never the less try your suggestion.